# Query loading forever

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a query which will create me a double label using one of the node proprieties. I can see how in the Neo4j browser the labels are created but the query still loads.

```
MATCH (n:Disease)
CALL apoc.create.addLabels( id(n), [ n.STY ] ) YIELD node
REMOVE node.STY
RETURN node;
```

I expect that this query will finish loading. Can someone explain to me why is this query loading forever? Is there a way of fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are the actions taken for each `Disease` node:

- Get the node
- Get its `STY` property value
- Call the APOC procedure. The procedure will:

  - Get the node yet again
  - Add the label
  - Return the node to the main query
- Remove the `STY` property
- Return the node

If there are a very large number of `Disease` nodes, then this could take a long time. Here are some suggestions.

And you should consider breaking up large transactions like this into multiple smaller ones, as that can reduce the amount of resources needed by the DB server. The [apoc.periodic.commit](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#periodic-commit) can help with that.

Also, if the number of different `STY` values is relatively small, reduce the number of APOC calls may help, like this:

```
MATCH (n:Disease)
WITH n.STY AS sty, COLLECT(n) AS ns
CALL apoc.create.addLabels(ns, [ sty ] ) YIELD node
REMOVE node.STY;
```

Notice that the above query also does not bother to return *every* `Disease` node, as that could cause problems for whatever is receiving the result (for example, the neo4j Browser cannot handle large results in a timely manner and can run out of memory).